# lambda expression to sort on min values in a group

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

my Table data is"

```
ExpenseID PersonID SeqNumb HistorySeqNumb HistoryCode
1            3       1          1            9
2            1       1          1            9
3            2       1          1            0
4            1       2          1            0
5            1       1          2            0
6            5       1          1            0
7            3       1          2            0
```

`ExpenseID` is primary Key column .
If a record is inserted for a `personID` it has a sequence of 1 and History Code indicating 0 is active record.If the record is edited a new row is inserted with current row historyCode changed to 9 and new row History Code 0and history Sequence 2.
If another new record is inserted for the same person it has a new row with incremented sequence number.

My resultSet should contain the active records and the order the records were inserted:

I need lambda expression

Output should be

```
ExpenseID PersonID SeqNumb HistorySeqNumb HistoryCode
7            3       1          2            0
5            1       1          2            0
3            2       1          1            0
4            1       2          1            0
6            5       1          1            0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result seems wrong to me...

1. You only want active records, ok check
2. The order they were inserted...

3 > 4 > 5 > 6 > 7 not 7 > 5 > 3 > 4 > 6

In the top table Person ID was added again giving it an ExpenseID of 7 which is fine, it should be first (if you are sorting in descending).  But then you have PersonID 1 with expense ID 5 when PersonID 5 with expense ID 6 was the previous record added before PersonID 3 with expense id 7

In short, your input data doesn't match your example desired output, making it rather difficult for anyone to answer you here.

From what I can see it looks like they should be sorted where HistoryCode = 0 Orderd By ExpenseID (bad database design comments aside)...

In such case it would be

```
var sortedItems = rawItems.Where(w => (w.HistoryCode == 0)).ToList();
sortedItems.Sort((emp1, emp2) => emp2.ExpenseID.CompareTo(emp1.ExpenseID));
//where rawItems is a List<Object> where object has properties for ExpenseID, PersonID... etc
```

Here is the entire Console App I made to experiment with this (bored), Add an Xml file called Data with the used Node/Attributes in it and set it to copy to output directory,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rawItems = new[] { new { ExpenseID = 0, PersonID = 0, SeqNumb = 0, HistorySeqNumb = 0, HistoryCode = 0 } }.ToList();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);                
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            fs.Flush();
            doc.Root.Elements("Item").ToList().ForEach(i =>
            {
                var xExpenseID = Convert.ToInt32(i.Attribute("ExpenseID").Value);
                var xPersonID = Convert.ToInt32(i.Attribute("PersonID").Value);
                var xSeqNumb = Convert.ToInt32(i.Attribute("SeqNumb").Value);
                var xHistorySeqNumb = Convert.ToInt32(i.Attribute("HistorySeqNumb").Value);
                var xHistoryCode = Convert.ToInt32(i.Attribute("HistoryCode").Value);
                rawItems.Add(new { ExpenseID = xExpenseID, PersonID = xPersonID, SeqNumb = xSeqNumb, HistorySeqNumb = xHistorySeqNumb, HistoryCode = xHistoryCode });
            });
        }

        //sort
        var sortedItems = rawItems.Where(w => (w.HistoryCode == 0)).ToList();
        sortedItems.Sort((emp1, emp2) => emp2.ExpenseID.CompareTo(emp1.ExpenseID));

        Console.Write("ExpenseID".PadRight(16, ' '));
        Console.Write("PersonID".PadRight(16, ' '));
        Console.Write("SeqNumb".PadRight(16, ' '));
        Console.Write("HistorySeqNumb".PadRight(16, ' '));
        Console.WriteLine("HistoryCode".PadRight(16, ' '));
        foreach (var item in sortedItems)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ExpenseID.ToString().PadRight(16, ' '));
            Console.Write(item.PersonID.ToString().PadRight(16, ' '));
            Console.Write(item.SeqNumb.ToString().PadRight(16, ' '));
            Console.Write(item.HistorySeqNumb.ToString().PadRight(16, ' '));
            Console.WriteLine(item.HistoryCode.ToString().PadRight(16, ' '));
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.But i need the order the record was inserted in the table

Comment: Try explaining a bit better than.. If ExpenseID is an auto ID Primary key, odering them in order is the order they were inserted into the table.

or better yet, just tweak the llambda I have above to do it in the right order.